# Encriptación precio en formulario de PayPal

Tags: encriptación, paypal

estoy integrando el pago con PayPal en un sitio web y tengo un problemilla, aunque parace que la integración funciona necesito poder encriptar datos como el precio antes de enviar el formulario que enlaza a paypal, he buscado in formacion y la verdad no estoy seguro de que esto se pueda hacer, pero es que me parece poco seguro porque cualquiera podría modificar el precio inspeccionando elemento

yo ahora mismo tengo algo asi:

```
<form id="formTpv" action="{PAYPAL_URL}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{PAYPAL_BUSINESS}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="{PAYPAL_CURRENCY_CODE}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{PAYPAL_RETURN}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="{PAYPAL_CANCEL_RETURN}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="{PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{$precio}" />
</form>
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Cualquiera puede modificar el precio, pero cuando llega la respuesta del pago, debes comprobar contra tu base de datos (donde registraste el pedido y su precio) que el valor pagado es el correcto, asi te olvidas de este problema. Si el monto no coincide, rechazas la operación y no entregas el producto al Usuario.

Comment: gracias, me fue util tu aportación